# How to get Keyboard on double tap on a text field

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, ios7

I am making a application in which I want keyboard on double-tap, I have disabled keyboard on single tap by using textfield delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    return NO; 
}
```

And after that I make a action method for textfield

```
[textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
```

And in this method I used this code:

```
[textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
```

But this is not working

Suggest me, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

First create a class variable of type Bool (say `BOOL shouldFire`) and initialise it to NO.
And add `UITapGestureRecogniser` with `number of taps = 2` to the UITextField.

When the selector attached to TapGesture fires, use below code

```
-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecogniser *)ges{
 _shouldFire=YES;
 [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And change your method to->

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{   
    if(self.shouldFire==YES){
      self.shouldFire=NO;
      return YES: 
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: how did you used my code? did you created shouldFire Bool or int ?show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well straight forward suggestion is to add a static variable

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    if(count%2 ==0)
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: if a user taps it two times seperately also, your code will make it responder. which is unwanted.

Comment: Then you can make count as IVAR and put a timer if there is no 2x clicks in x time make it be 0 again.In addition to my answer I mean.

Comment: if a user taps it two times seperately also, your code will make it responder. which is unwanted.

Comment: read my comment -> if you don't get it -> then I explain you just doing it manually you defining the window of time for user to tap.